# VSCode The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 17 is used

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[i have this problem on vscode for a java project. i've also other java projects, but they're not giving me any problems. this is the only one with this issue. can anyone help to solve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqzuB.png)

i already tried adding the java installation path to the java home settings in vs code. but nothing happened.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: If you had read [ask], you would have seen that you shouldn't upload images of code, errors, logs, or other text. You would also have seen that you need to describe the problem in a way that others can reproduce it.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the version in your pom.xml file, then update your project config in order to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) to get started with java.

This [configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects) can set the **JDk**

```json
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
    "path": "/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_201"
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-11",
    "path": "/usr/local/jdk-11.0.3",
    "sources" : "/usr/local/jdk-11.0.3/lib/src.zip",
    "javadoc" : "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api",
    "default":  true
   },
   {
    "name": "JavaSE-12",
    "path": "/usr/local/jdk-12.0.2"
   },
]
```